# IIS Server and Azure AD

Tags: azure, iis-7, office365api, office365-apps, azure-active-directory

I am building a Office 365 application using ASP.net Visual studio 2015 Enterprise. When I run the application in visual studio using **IIS Express** it run fine everything works. I am able to authenticate with Azure AD and be routed back to my start page. However, when I deploy it to the **IIS SERVER**, I am able to authenticate but after authenticating I am routed back to a WHITE screen. 
FIREWALL is off
I DO NOT WANT TO HOST IN THE CLOUD!!
I tried using Fiddler but that didn't help me that much. Have anyone ever ran into this problem or similar? Were you able to get around it without hosting in the cloud?

Comment: A white screen doesn't tell anyone much. What error code are you getting back from your app? A 404, a 500? Have you configured your reply URL properly in Azure AD?

Comment: Yes I did configure my URL in Azure AD it is correct. As I mentioned in the question. IT **works** in **IIS Express** but NOT **IIS Server**. If the reply URL was wrong then I would get and error page back from microsoft saying that I have not configure this URL in my reply list on AZURE.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem - it worked fine in IIS Express, but in IIS I would get a 400-Bad Request (header too large) error and the page would just spin. To fix this:

1. Make sure your app login and your reply URL are the same in Azure. Make sure the `PostLogoutRedirectUri` in your app matches as well.
2. That URL in step 1 should not be a page! This is what got me I think. I had https://localhost/testdirectory/default.aspx when I should have only had https://localhost/testdirectory/. Once all 3 places matched, things started working in IIS as well.
3. You probably know this but make sure you're using HTTPS, not HTTP.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just a little note for the future: signature lines aren't required (or even encouraged) here - your profile icon in the corner is usually all you need. I've edited that out for now though, but I thought I'd let you know so you understand why that happened.